# Text in div is automatically going to the bottom

Tags: css, html

My text is at the bottom of the `div` but it need to be at the top of the `div`.

[Picture of the issue.](http://d.pr/i/eRpM+)

My CSS code:

```
#pagetitle
{
    float: left;
    width: 472px;
    height: 109px;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-family: 'CodePro';
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

html, body{
    margin:0 !important;
    padding:0 !important;
    opacity: 0.99;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

    background-color: #cfcfcf;
}
```

live preview is at [link](http://www.random-radio.net/)

Comment: Your text *is* at the top of the div (try adding enough text/elements to make it wrap around).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#pagetitle
{
    line-height: 23px; /* or so, it depends on your need*/
}
```

Comment: #pagetitle
{
    line-height:23px;
}

Comment: This was my solution as well. If it's not working, post your browser and OS.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it has somethign to do with the font family(CodePro) you are using, if you change the font family to something like Helvetica, you would see the effect you would expect. You can adjust the position of the text in a couple of different ways.

```
margin-top: -30px;
```

or

```
line-height: 40px;
```

to the **#pagetitle**, to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

It is the font and size of the font that does it. You could give it some minus margin or some line height.

```
#pagetitle {
   margin-top: -30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
#pagetitle
{
    line-height: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If its an issue to use the line-height property. I always feel safe using...

```
position:relative;
top:-20px;
```

in

```
#pagetitle
    {
        float: left;
        width: 472px;
        height: 109px;
        font-size: 80px;
        font-family: 'CodePro';
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        position:relative;
        top:-20px;
    }
```

Play around with `top:-20px` to get the desired result.